# Strange web inspector lag in both Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, web-inspector

I’m experiencing this odd issue where the web inspector in both Safari and Chrome don’t refresh after a full page reload until about 10–20 seconds later, and only with the web app I’m building. Anyone ever seen anything like this?

[Here is a video showing the issue.](http://cloud.smallparade.com/fbXS)

The video starts with a page refresh. When you see the blue screen that means the page is fully refreshed. A full 13 seconds later you’ll see the content of the inspector on the right refresh.

This is a relatively heavy React app I’m building, but actual browser performance has been great. I see no lag times or chuggy responses in the actual UI. Only this strange inspector issue. Safari fares slightly better, but still a weird lag.

I’ve no idea if this is a React issue, an OSX issue, a browser issue, or something else entirely. Happy to move this to the appropriate place once I find out (fingers crossed).

Comment: could be some infinite loop / memory leak problem. At least this is what I would check at first